# Increase name by 1

Tags: c#, string, text

How can I increase the name by 1 each time the number crosses 45?

Simply, when I have **NAME:45**, I need the next name to be **NAME1:1**.
Its pretty simple. But the thing is, I already have a counter to look the change from 45 to 1. And this is because I don't know what to do with the above situation??
How can I do this??

My code snippet:

```
public void reccurent()
{ //Here we are exporting header
        string[] strLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
        string CarouselName = enter.Text;
        int[] cols = new int[] { 15, 15, 25, 15, 15 };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string[] cells = line.Replace("\"", "").Split('\t');
           //removing double woutes in the textfile
        for (int c = 0; c < cells.Length; c++)
            sb.Append(cells[c].Replace(" ", "_").PadRight(cols[c]));
                 //replacing all spaces with underscore in the header column
        sb.AppendLine("Location".PadRight(15));
        //adding a coumn called LOCATION
        sb.AppendLine();
        int repeater = 45; // change me
        int tmpCarousel = 0;
        int carouselNumber = 0;
        Dictionary<string, int> namesForCarousels = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < textfile.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < cells.Length; c++)
                sb.Append(textfile[i].Cells[c].Replace(" ", "_").PadRight(cols[c]));
                   //replacing all spaces with underscore in each column values
            string name = textfile[i].Cells[1];

            if (namesForCarousels.TryGetValue(name, out tmpCarousel) == false)
            {
                carouselNumber++;
                if (carouselNumber > 45)
                    carouselNumber = 1;//resetting to number1, but name is

                namesForCarousels[name] = carouselNumber;
            }
            string num = carouselNumber < repeater ? "" : (carouselNumber / repeater).ToString();

            var strCorousel = lstMX.Find(x => x.MAX_PN.Equals(name)).Carousel;
            strCorousel = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strCorousel)) ? CarouselName : strCorousel;
            sb.Append(String.Format("{0}:{1}", strCorousel + num, 1 + carouselNumber % repeater).PadRight(15));
           // carouselNumber++;
            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\output.TXT", sb.ToString());
    }
```

Output is coming as:

```
  NAME:2  // name is stating from2...
  NAME:3
  .
  .
  .
  NAME:45 //after the 45.. its going perfect to NAME1:1
  NAME1:1   //but after NAME1:1 its going to NAME
  NAME:2
```

Comment: If your name is always "NAME" what does... `name = textfile[i].Cells[1];` do?   Is this supposed to handle duplicate names and save them as uniquely named files?  So in practice the names of the files will be something other than "NAME"?

Comment: @Kevin please see my current entire codes:::

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example with 3 instead of 45

```
int repeater = 3; // change me
string name = "NAME";
int carouselNumber = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    string num = carouselNumber < repeater ? ":" : (carouselNumber / repeater).ToString() + ":";
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", name + num, 1 + carouselNumber % repeater);
    carouselNumber++;
}
```

For

```
NAME:   1
NAME:   2
NAME:   3
NAME1:  1
NAME1:  2
NAME1:  3
NAME2:  1
NAME2:  2
NAME2:  3
NAME3:  1
NAME3:  2
NAME3:  3
NAME4:  1
NAME4:  2
NAME4:  3
NAME5:  1
NAME5:  2
NAME5:  3
NAME6:  1
NAME6:  2
NAME6:  3
```

Comment: i changed the codes.. it almost coming... But.. my names now starts from NAME:2.. and after NAME:45.. its going perfectly to NAME1:1. but after that its going to NAME:2// `Please see my entire code and out put here` http://pastie.org/9712160

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach. There's obviously many ways to do this.

```
var testCounter = "NAME1";


for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(testCounter, @"(?<label>NAME)(?<counter>\d+)(?::(?<robinCounter>\d+))?");
    if (m.Success)
    {
        var count = Int32.Parse(m.Groups["counter"].Value);

        var roundRobinCounter = 0;
        if (m.Groups["robinCounter"].Success)
            roundRobinCounter = Int32.Parse(m.Groups["robinCounter"].Value);

        count++;
        if (count == 46)
        {
            count = 1;
            roundRobinCounter++;
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", m.Groups["label"].Value, count);
        if (roundRobinCounter != 0)
            sb.AppendFormat(":{0}", roundRobinCounter);

        testCounter = sb.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(testCounter);
    }
}
```

It just uses a regex to parse the text each time you need to increment. I didn't include all of the error handling, but you should be able to pick it up from here.

Here's a breakdown of the regex

```
(?<label>           -- Start a named group capture called "label"
   NAME             -- Search for the literal "NAME"
)
(?<counter>         -- Start a named group capture called "counter"
   \d+              -- Search for one or more digits
)
(?:                 -- Start a non-capture group
:                   -- Find a literal colon, and stop the previous digit search
(?<robinCounter>    -- Start a named group capture called "robinCounter"
   \d+              -- Find one or more digits (continues to end of the string or when a non-didgit is found)
)
)?                  -- End the non-capture group, and make the group optional (the question mark means find 0 or 1 time)
```

**EDIT** I updated the code to reflect the output you provided.

Here's some example output from the code above:

```
NAME40
NAME41
NAME42
NAME43
NAME44
NAME45
NAME1:1
NAME2:1
NAME3:1
NAME4:1
NAME5:1
NAME6:1
```

Comment: Now every where name is coming as `NAME1:0  `

Comment: @Stacy: Can you please be a little more descriptive? You may have to provide the code you integrated. I attached the output from the code I provided. I did update the code a couple minutes ago. You added the example output after I was in the process of posting.

Comment: I will update you the codes.. in paste.bin.. please hold on a sec